# Is it possible to take screenshot of visible part of page in InternetExplorerDriver?

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium-iedriver

I need to take screenshot of only visible part of the page in IEDriver to have consistency with other drivers. With other drivers I use "scroll and stitch" method to get full height page image, but in some cases there can be differences - for example if page has sticky header. I would rather go one way or another, but same for all drivers, and not all drivers provide ability to take full page screenshot.

Docs for TakesScreenshot interface states this:

> For WebDriver extending TakesScreenshot, this makes a best effort depending on the browser to return the following in order of preference:
>
> - Entire page
> - Current window
> - Visible portion of the current frame
> - The screenshot of the entire display containing the browser

**My question is:**

Is it possible to force Internet Explorer to take screenshot only of current window? I know it is not possible via API but maybe there is some custom capability or internal driver setting which can be changed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found this information in Internet Explorer Driver Server changelog:

> ## v2.52.0.0
>
> - Release to synchronize with release of Selenium project.
> - Updates to JavaScript automation atoms.
> - (on behalf of Anton Usmansky) **Added ie.enableFullPageScreenshot capability**
>     to allow users to create screenshots of only the current view port. The
>     capability defaults to true, which preserves the original behavior of 
>     resizing the browser window and taking a screenshot of the full page.

I tried it and it actually works! Example code for Java (works with with IE11 - I didn't test it with other versions):

```java
DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
caps.setCapability("ie.enableFullPageScreenshot", false);
WebDriver driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(caps);
```